# PowerShell 3 PSCustomObject displays in stupid mode via a variable

Tags: powershell-3.0

PowerShell 3.0 gave us PSCustomObject as a type which allows proper table formatting, like this:

```
> [PSCustomObject]@{ Day = "Monday"; Task = "Wash car" }

Day     Task
---     ----
Monday   Wash car
```

(see http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/scriptfanatic/archive/2012/04/13/Custom-objects-default-display-in-PowerShell-3-0.aspx)

But if I go via a variable, it reverts to stupid mode.

```
> [PSCustomObject]$row = @{ Day = "Monday"; Task = "Wash car" }
> $row

Name    Value
---     ----
Task    Wash car
Day     Monday
```

Why? (thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it almost immediately.

```
[PSCustomObject]$row = [PSCustomObject]@{ Day = "Monday"; Task = "Wash car" }
```

Effectively, I was creating and casting a hashtable to a PSCustomObject. Still not entirely sure why the hashtable keys aren't turned into properties like a .NET 4.0 DLR ExpandoObject.

Much better to write CmdLets in C#.

Comment: Just want to note that in PowerShell 2, this would still result in type Hashtable, not PSCustomObject. Had this same exact issue and couldn't figure it out till I saw this question and realized that my issue is the PowerShell version.